# How do I play a local DVD copy in "DVD mode" using Xine and/or Mplayer?

Tags: linux, video, dvd, mplayer, xine

I have a local copy of entire DVD's VIDEO_TS directory.

How can I use Xine or Mplayer to play it in a "DVD mode"?

That means for me:

- that menus are recognized as such,
- I can select language and other DVD-related options from DVD's menu,
  rather than from command line
- I can navigate through titles, rather than VOB files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your dvd folder is /path/to/movie/VIDEO_TS, try

```
xine dvd:///path/to/movie/
```

or

```
vlc dvd:///path/to/movie/
```

mplayer plays the movie, but I couldn't get it to play it in DVD mode. Apparently, the packaged builds of mplayer don't quite have [menu navigation support](http://linuxtidbits.wordpress.com/2009/04/10/mplayer-with-dvds/) yet.

```
mplayer dvd:// -dvd-device '/path/to/movie'
```

If your build of mplayer has dvd menu support, you should be able to invoke it using *dvdnav://* instead of *dvd://*

Comment: Thank you very much! dvdnav:// was the solution to what I was looking for.